# CFFI and win32 clipboard access

Tags: winapi, common-lisp, cffi

I'm a newbie in Common Lisp and did some experiments on it.
I was trying hard to get some access to the windows clipboard, then I found this reference:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.lisp/hyNqn2QhUY0

That was perfect, except for it was tailored for CLISP FFI, and I wanted it working with CFFI.
 Then I tried to convert the code, and partially succeed but there's a problem with the routine
 (get-clip-string), testing with Clozure CL 1.10 on WinXP(!):

Test text: Have Space Suit-Will Travel

? (get-clip-string)

> Error: The value "Have Space Suit-Will Travel" is not of the expected type (UNSIGNED-BYTE 32).
>   While executing: GLOBAL-LOCK-STRING, in process listener(1).
>   Type :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
>   Type :? for other options.

I think I didn't get the type thing on CFFI (although I've read the manual), or the original prescription on CLISP. have someone any hint?
 the following sequence of commands work, but I'm afraid that's not secure:

```
(open-clip 0)
(get-clip 1)
(close-clip 0)
```

(open-clip 0)
(get-clip 1)
(close-clip 0)

here is the code:

```
(ql:quickload :cffi)


(cffi:load-foreign-library "user32.dll")

(cffi:load-foreign-library "kernel32.dll")

(cffi:load-foreign-library "msvcrt.dll")


(cffi:defcfun ("GetClipboardData" get-clip) :string

(uformat  :unsigned-int))


(cffi:defcfun ("OpenClipboard" open-clip) :int

  (hOwner  :unsigned-int))


(cffi:defcfun ("CloseClipboard" close-clip) :int


      (hOwner  :unsigned-int))


(cffi:defcfun ("EmptyClipboard" empty-clip) :int)


(cffi:defcfun ("SetClipboardData" set-clip) :int

  (data  :unsigned-int)

  (format :unsigned-int))


(cffi:defcfun ("GlobalAlloc" global-alloc) :int

  (flags  :unsigned-int)

  (numbytes :unsigned-int))


(cffi:defcfun ("GlobalLock" global-lock) :unsigned-int

  (typ  :unsigned-int))


(cffi:defcfun ("GlobalLock" global-lock-string) :string 

  (typ  :unsigned-int))


(cffi:defcfun ("GlobalUnlock" global-unlock) :int

  (typ  :unsigned-int))


(cffi:defcfun ("memcpy" memcpy) :int

  (dest  :unsigned-int)

  (src :string) 

  (coun :unsigned-int))



(defun get-clip-string ()

          (open-clip 0)

          (let* ((h (get-clip 1)) (s (global-lock-string h)))

                 (global-unlock h) (close-clip 0) s))


(defun set-clip-string (s)

          (let* ((slen (+ 1 (length s)))(newh (global-alloc 8194 slen))

(newp (global-lock newh)))

          (memcpy newp s (+ 1 slen)) (global-unlock newh) (open-clip 0)

(set-clip 1 newh) (close-clip 0)))
```

Comment: Without much insight, I would suggest figuring out how `:string` and `(unsigned-byte 32)` are being related, and maybe change to something else; eg, perhaps the Windows API is returning `(unsigned-byte 16)` or `(unsigned-byte 8)` characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the return type you used for `GetClipboardData` and the argument type you used for `GlobalLock` and `GlobalUnlock`. You define `GetClipboardData` to return a string, but in C, `GetClipboardData` returns a `HANDLE`, which is defined as a pointer to `void`, and the argument accepted by `GlobalLock` and `GlobalUnlock` is also a `HANDLE`. Change your C function definitions to this:

```
(cffi:defcfun ("GetClipboardData" get-clip) :pointer
    (uformat  :unsigned-int))

(cffi:defcfun ("GlobalLock" global-lock-string) :string 
    (type  :pointer))

(cffi:defcfun ("GlobalUnlock" global-unlock) :int
    (type  :pointer))
```

...and the problem goes away.

You also need to fix the other `global-lock-*` functions and also `memcpy` if you want to use `set-clip-string`.

There's another bug, though: When you type-correct the entire program so that the `set-clip-string` function can also be called, then `set-clip-string` only seems to be able to put a string onto a clipboard that is local to the Lisp process (I'm using a console build of SBCL via SLIME on Win7). Suppose you copied `Have Space Suit-Will Travel` to the Clipboard with Notepad. Then try this:

```
CL-USER> (set-clip-string "MY CLIPBOARD")
1
CL-USER> (get-clip-string)
"MY CLIPBOARD"
```

So it seems to have worked. But then if you try to paste into EMACS from the Clipboard using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ins</kbd>, you get:

```
CL-USER> Have Space Suit-Will Travel
```

So the *real* clipboard still has what Notepad put there, and your Lisp program only has a private clipboard that can't be used to copy data to other programs, not even the EMACS session that is hosting it.

This is happening because `set-clip-string` needs to call `empty-clip` after calling `open-clip`.

Also, every one of those Windows calls can fail, but your code doesn't check for failures or handle errors.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I see, how much I need to learn :-)  Oddly the argument type :pointer in the function global-unlock worked only for the procedure get-clip-string - I needed to keep a separate function with argument :unsigned-int for set-clip-string... The return type of get-clip changed to :pointer also worked correctly. Thanks again!